# How do I pivot simple repeating data in SQL 2005 that is of type Text

Tags: sql, pivot

I've done some searching and found info on how to pivot numbers and sum them, but I haven't seen where I can pivot text.

Simplified, we have a table that looks a little something like this...

```
PlanID    AreaAbbrev    AreaDescription    GoalText
10133     Rec           Recreation         Johnny is good at...
10133     Community     Community Part     Johnny is currently going...
10133     Employment    Employment         Johnny is currently employed at...
10144     Rec           Recreation         Sammy is good at...
10144     Community     Community Part     Sammy is currently going...
10144     Employment    Employment         Sammy is currently employed at...
```

You can see there's always three different AreaAbbrev and they repeat.  AND you can see that the GoalText can be lengthy and is always different.

Here's what I'd like the new Select to look like.

```
PlanID    Recreation            Community Part                Employment
10133     Johnny is good at..   Johnny is currently going...  Johnny is currently employeed at...
10144     Sammy is good at..    Sammy is currently going...   Sammy is currently employed at...
```

Sorry for all the dashes... I tried 4 or 5 different ways to display these tables and this was all I could work out.  I had to use the dashes as spaces to get it lined up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Pivot` function always needs an Agregate function to work. So, as you cannot use `SUM` or `AVG`, you can use the `MIN` or `MAX`.

So, here´s a piece of code to get what you want.

```
SELECT PlanId, [Recreation], [Community party], [Employment]
FROM 
(SELECT PlanId, AreaDescription, GoalText
FROM dbo.TempArea) p
PIVOT
(
MAX (GoalText)
FOR AreaDescription IN
( [Recreation], [Community party], [Employment] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY PlanId
```

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the other answer, you can use a PIVOT.  But if you do not have a known number of records to transform then you can use a dynamic PIVOT.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc404/1)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.areadescription) 
            FROM t c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT planid, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select planid, areadescription, goaltext
                from t
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(goaltext)
                for areadescription in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```